# cURL can't connect in a free host but works fine in my localhost

Tags: php, curl, twitter, oauth

I created a small web app, with the feature of being able to Sign in with a Twitter account, by connecting with OAuth. It worked like charm for a few months, but now it stopped working. This is a quick and summarized overview  "Sign in with twitter" algorithm.

- Collecting some parameters (timestamp, nonce, some kind of application ID and so)
- Use this parameters to create a new URL that looks like this:
  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=DLZZTIxpY19FnWJNtqw5A&oauth_nonce=1369452195&oauth_signature=DIetumiKqJu66XXVvDDHdepnP9M%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1369452195&oauth_version=1.0
- Connect to that URL and retrieve the data, it has an access token
- Continue doing fun stuff using that access token.

The URL generated in step 2 is fine because I tried manually copying it in Google Chrome, and it shows a beautiful access token, so the problem isn't there (I think). 
In the step 3, I have a really small method that should do some very basic stuff: Connect to the URL generated before, retrieve the content and return it.

In my localhost Using EasyPHP 12.1, it works perfectly, as usual, but in the free host that i'm using (000webhost) it doesn't work anymore. When trying to connect, it just timeouts. The HTTPCodeError is 0 and the CurlError is "Couldn't connect to host".

This is the method used to connect to the URL.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $response;
```

And this is an example of a URL used with that method:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=DLZZTIxpY19FnWJNtqw5A&oauth_nonce=1369452195&oauth_signature=DIetumiKqJu66XXVvDDHdepnP9M%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1369452195&oauth_version=1.0

I've been trying to fix it all day long, but now I have no idea even of what to try. The files are the very same in my localhost and in the 000webhost.
If you could enlighten me I would be very happy. I'll take my pants off for answers if it's needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that Twitter has blacklisted (blocked) your free host's servers or IP address. This can happen if other users on the server abuse the API.

Comment: Sounds like you are right... well, i'll try to contact Twitter support team to see if they can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @user2376733 Were you ever able to fix the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: same here. Is this problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that your [free web hosting service](http://weloveourhost.com/free-services.html) blocks it. You know these services are perfect as long as everything is very simple. The moment things become complicated you run into restrictions implemented by the provider. Most of these services limit band width, disk space, server use, support, uploading and more.