# Why wont twitter api work live but work locally

Tags: php, twitter

I've used 3 different libraries to access my usertimeline using twitter API 1.1

All 3 work fine testing locally using WAMP but when I upload to my host server (000webhost) it causes the page to timeout and gives me a 324 error no data received.

Anyone come across this issue or have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Switch webhosts. Seriously. Or better yet, get your own VPS (May I suggest digitalocean?)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I've been having the same problem, it looks like either Twitter blocks links from 000WH or 000WH blocks requests to Twitter, because of past attacks. If you look at some of the forums, it looks like they may not reverse the block.

See:
[cURL can't connect in a free host but works fine in my localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746170/curl-cant-connect-in-a-free-host-but-works-fine-in-my-localhost)
http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/34393-cant-post-twitter-anymore.html